# What type of loop to use for this code in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I'm not too sure on what type of loops to use, the class power point isn't really getting the point across and I have no idea what to do

```
      {
        string name;
        double sales;

        //start loop here to ask user for employee info

        name =GetName("name");
        //Start a loop here to ask for the sales of each day
        sales1 = GetSales("day 1 sales");
        sales2 = GetSales("day 2 sales");
        sales3 = GetSales("day 3 sales");
        sales4 = GetSales("day 4 sales");
        sales5 = GetSales("day 5 sales");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        //End loop here asking for sales of each day 

        Employee emp1 = new Employee( );


        Display(emp1);

//End loop here asking for employee info
```

In a previous program we have used

```
    {
        name = GetInput("name");
        grade1 = int.Parse(GetInput("first grade"));
        grade2 = int.Parse(GetInput("second grade"));
        grade3 = int.Parse(GetInput("third grade"));
    }

    public static string GetInput(string temp)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your {0}: ", temp);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

to get the user to input multiple numbers and a name but my prof wants this in a loop but I have no idea how to convert this into a loop

Comment: What loops do you know? What is it you're trying to reach? What loop does the job?

Comment: I think your loop starting point might need adjusting.  Loops typically take the redundancy out of code, so the obvious place I see would be setting the value in sales.

Comment: Typically you open a stream to get user input.  If it were a loop to ask for different things then that *would* make sense.  I'm not sure what is meant by "start a loop to ask for X" as in a single thing...  Is that what the instructions say verbatim?

Comment: Im supposed to ask for a name then five different numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [C sharp- ask for a name and six different number then add the numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941860/c-sharp-ask-for-a-name-and-six-different-number-then-add-the-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Put the strings into an array and use a for loop

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [string array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ch45axte.aspx) like this:

```
string name = "name" ;
string names = "names";
string named = "named";
string nameds = "nameds";

string[] strArray = new string[] { name, names, named, nameds };

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
{
   MessageBox.Show(strArray[i].ToString());
}
```

**NOTE:** You will need to change the variables to something that meets your requirements, and the `MessageBox` is just to show you that the strings are populated into the array and retrieved via the `for loop`.

Comment: Right back at you!  I think we were typing our answers at the same time, haha.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a while loop

with the exit condition being, while user did not press "exit" you could make exit be equal to a value

Comment: So if I wanted the user to stop inputting numbers after the fifth sales number, where would i put the counter?

Answer (score 1):

This would be suitable for one employee

```
double sales[] = new double[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sales[i] = GetSales("day " + (i + 1) + " sales");
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}

Employee emp = new Employee();
```

Extend this solution to meet your needs.